# Capturing text from windows applications

Tags: export, text, dump

I had an application a while back that would allow me to dump text from any application on screen to a text file. Unfortunately, I used it so rarely that I don't remember what the name of it was. I found a similar application here: http://www.skesoft.com/textcatch.htm. Does anyone know of an open-source alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google for help. You might want to look at

CopyText: http://www10.pair.com/vsap/
Or that comparison from [alt.comp.freeware](http://www.pricelesswarehome.org/acf/P_TEXT.php#1.09CopyText%28DifficultWindows%29)

Comment: That comparison table is great. I ended up going with TextGrabber (http://marmro.homeip.net/Description/TextGrabber-v1_11.zip.html), which is open source and free. Some time when I get a chance I'll try to add some of these apps to AlternativeTo.net